MotW: Which bonuses stack?
As far as I can tell, there are:

Stat bonuses
Ongoing
Forward

Do these stack with each other or themself? One can easily imagine scenario where two Ongoing bonuses would apply, for example. Should they stack, or should I just pick the highest one?
Intuitively, I would allow stacking one per category, but I am new to the system.

Stack 'em to the heavens*.

Often the rules for a move will tell you to roll, say, +Cool. This means you should grab two everyday six-sided dice, roll them, add them together and then add whatever number is written down for your hunter's Cool.
[...] Sometimes a move will give you a bonus to future dice rolls: you get to take the bonus "forward" or "ongoing". [...] If you get +1 forward, you get +1 on your very next roll only. [...] If you get +1 ongoing, you get +1 to every roll you make until the situation no longer applies.
-- "Rolling the Dice", Monster of the Week 2nd Edition pp. 111-2

Not listed are cases where you just "get +1", such as The Monstrous's playbook ability to get +1 to Investigate a Mystery when assuming the form of an animal whose senses might help. That +1 is a situation that never stops applying, so to speak. The Help Out move also gives a +1 bonus, but this bonus isn't annotated for a different reason - it stops immediately, since it only applies to a move that another hunter is rolling right now.
All of these bonuses stack with each other, without limit.
*Well, almost without limit.
You may notice that the only basic move that gives you +1 ongoing, Read a Bad Situation, also says that if you orchestrate a situation where multiple of your asked questions apply, such as taking your best way out while protecting the victims, you only get +1 from the move.
"Per move" is probably a good limiter for +1 ongoing situations, for other investigate-type moves the various playbooks have access to, like The Spooky's Tune In.
Also, if you think you've created a situation where by rule you're adding multiple different stat bonuses to a roll, you might want to check things over again; usually when the rules say a different stat gets involved, it gets added to the roll instead of whatever stat the move originally called for.
But the Keeper has final authority over who gets the spotlight.
As a result the Keeper gets to decide who rolls when for what and under which circumstances.
If Susanna hits a roll to Kick Some Ass and passes a +1 forward to Azrael to follow up on it, it's natural for the Keeper to immediately swing over to Azrael and prompt them to act, roll, and use that +1.
If Bradley Reads a Bad Situation to get +1 ongoing to take some actions, those actions are based on specific questions his player asks the Keeper. When the Keeper gives those answers they should know the limits of the bad situation and therefore what kinds of actions actually represent Bradley following up on the answers. If Bradley asks after his best way out on the top floor of a school that's being pulled into the underworld, but instead runs down into the basement to do whatever a hunter would want to do down there, he's put himself into a different situation and the best way out no longer applies.
In practice, most situations where people get +1 forward or ongoing are related either to choices they've made openly in front of everyone or to answers the Keeper gave, and it's part of the Keeper's responsibility to follow those bonuses around, to go where the players chose and be aware of where the Keeper hinted.
